# Ошибка импорта scikit-learn. ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size

Tags: python, python-import, scikit-learn

Когда я пытаюсь импортировать `scikit-learn`, я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я обновила `numpy`, `pandas` и `scikit-learn`, используя `pip`, но это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом, вы используете * PyCharm *, как я вижу, а также вы используете * консоль Python *.

Выполните следующие действия:

1. одним из вариантов является выбор дистрибутива python на вашем компьютере в соответствии с тем, который вы первоначально устанавливали в терминале в окне интерпретатора проекта.
2. Второй вариант - это вариант с небольшим количеством настроек и установкой пакета из окна списка пакетов.

*** PyCharm / Preferences ... / go down on Project: "your_project_name" / Project Interpreter *** и выберите переводчика, что вам нужно. `Здесь вы можете выбрать один из пакетов aka machine python или выбрать другой, также известный как виртуальный env или conda etc`.

Одна нижняя страница \, как вы можете видеть ниже; является плюсом, поэтому знак откроет окно «Доступные пакеты» и на панели поиска просто введите ** scikit-learn ** и выберите, если вы хотите, чтобы ваш пользовательский каталог Или нет, нажмите кнопку «Установить пакет» (в нижнем левом углу).

Для получения дополнительной информации, проверьте ответ на английском языке.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439347/cant-import-scikit-learn-valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size/43439837#43439837